# What is the right design pattern to get a prototype-bean from a component-bean?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, lifetime

I am just wondering what a good architecture design looks like.

- Let's say we have a `CarRepository` which manages all beans of type `Car` in a car rental application.
- `Car` beans are of type prototype
- `CarRepository` bean is of type repository (singleton)
- Now, the `CarRepository` is asked to create a new `Car` bean, e.g. when the rental company has bought a new car.

Of course, I could implement `ApplicatioContextAware` and use `context.getBean("car")`, but for me, it doesn't fit well to the idea of dependency injection. What is best-practice for injecting a shorter-lived bean into a singleton?

Update: Maybe I should add an example to make it more clear.

```
@Repository
public class CarRepository {
private List<Car> cars;

    public void registerNewCar(int id, String model) {
        // I don't want to access the Spring context via ApplicationContextAware here

        // Car tmp = (Car) context.getBean("car");
        // car.setId(id);
        // car.setModel(model);
        // cars.add(tmp);
    }
}

@Scope("prototype")
public class Car {
    private int id;
    private String model;

    // getter and setters
}
```

Comment: Your Car class should not be a bean in such case. It should probably be an entity. See JPA / Spring data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring offers a mechanism that handles injecting a shorter-lived bean in a longer-lived one. It's called a scoped proxy. How it works is that the singleton is injected with a proxy that will handle method calls by searching the shorter scope (like session or request) for a bean instance and delegating to that instance.

You didn't specify, if you are using xml or annotations to configure your application or what version of Spring you are using. You can read more about configuring the scope proxy with xml in the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection). I'm going to give you an example how to configure it with annotations in a Spring 4-ish environment.

For me the best way is to use the meta-annotations mechanism. It allows you to create your own annotations that will be later used by Spring to configure your app. For example:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public @interface SessionScoped{
}
```

Such an annotation, when specified on a @Component (or @Service or any other specialization) class or a @Bean method in your Java config will cause that bean to be injected as a proxy. For example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class MyConfig{

    @SessionScoped
    @Bean
    public MyClass myBean(){
        // return your bean
    }
}
```

**All that being said, your example really makes me think you should be working with entities (Car) and repositories. See [Spring Data](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) if you are designing the model layer and you want to store Cars data in your database etc.**

Comment: I added an example to make it more clear. I will have a look at your hint and links - thanks! I am using Spring 4.1 and annotation-based configurations

Comment: And I bolded out the most important part of my answer in this case :)

Comment: Thanks! I will figure it out in the next days. Just for my understanding: What possibilities exist apart from this example? So let's say it is not about repositories and entities but just some application logic where I have a singleton-bean and some shorter-lived (prototype) beans... **How do I get new prototype beans injected into the singleton bean?**

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use `context.getBean(...)`, then, you can construct the car using `new Car(...)` as it will have same effect.

These are only two ways!

Comment: Not true, if the car bean is to be injected with any other dependencies or be managed by Spring in any other way.

Comment: ...especially it doesn't fit to my understanding of dependency injection. In my CarRepository, I want to declare what (prototype) beans I need... and not access the spring context to get the beans on myself.

Comment: @Apokralipsa Normally, Car does not seem like something you want Spring to manage.  We all have written DAOs (aka Repository), and when was last time someone used Prototype bean for Entities

Comment: @Christian  Why you need Car to be a prototype? I am not sure it should ideally have any dependency - unless you are implementing something like ActiveRecord

Comment: @Wand Maker exactly. That is why I mentioned entities and added a link to Spring Data in my answer. But that does not mean, that constructing objects by calling the constructor is an equivalent of calling context#getBean for prototype beans.